# Show that $f: K_1(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is Lipschitz.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

Firstly, the Assignment:

> Let $V = (\mathbb{R}^3 ,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ where $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ denotes the maximum norm and consider the function:
>
> $$f: K_1(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{8}(x+e^y+e^z)\\\frac{1}{8}(x+y+e^z)\\\frac{1}{8}(x+y+z)\\\end{pmatrix}$$
>   Show that $f$ is Lipschitz and determine a Lipschitz constant.
>
> Hint: Use common tools from differentiation to get the inequalities you need.

What I know is that I need to show that for arbitary $x, x' \in K_1(0)$:
$\|f(x) - f(x')\| ≤ \lambda \cdot \|x-x'\|$. I'm pretty sure (with the hint) that I will use the MVT eventually, but I don't know how to simplify the $\|$. For $\|x-x'\|$ I thought about assume that the difference between the first two entries are the maximum, since it'd make no difference later, but I don't know how to determine which entry of the functions values' differences is the maximum.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you compute the Jacobian and the take its norm, would it not be enough since $\lambda\le || Df || = \max_{||x||=1} || Df(x) \cdot x||$ ?

Comment: What is a Jacobian?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: What is $K_1(0)$? What norm is used on the domain of $f$? What norm is used on the codomain (range) of $f$? You defined $V$ but it never appears again.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the ball with radius 1 around the 0.